# Валидация полей jsp страницы из java бина

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp

Здравствуйте! Не так давно пишу что-то на java ee, так что надеюсь моё объяснение будет понятным)
В общем: при нажатии на кнопку "сохранить" на jsp странице, происходит проверка введенной инф. в поля странички (проверка нетривиальная так сказать), проверка происходит в бине и если все нормально то инф. сохраняется в БД... 
Но меня интересует как сделать так, что бы при не пройденной проверке, у соответствующих полей появлялись сообщения об ошибки.
При пройденной валидации осуществляется переход на главную страничку, при не пройденной переход не осуществляется, пользователь попадает на ту же страничку.
 P.S. Думал уже попробовать за js взяться (на js почти ни когда не писал), но понял что и так будет много проблем... но если кто то знает как на js такое реализовать буду рад помощи.

Comment: Spring MVC используй http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/

Comment: Вы уж определитесь, на js писать или jsp обрабатывать. Второй вариант даже при валидации на клиенте все же нужен для безопасности. А так можете, если страница не прошла валидацию, на jsp страничке под нужными полями формы завести переменные какие, и эту jsp в requestDispatcher поместить, с помощью jstl в них устанавливать сообщения об ошибке, и форвард сделать. Вообще масса вариантов